# Sequent and Gentzen calculus formulae

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

The text I am following at present, V. Manca's *Logica matematica* ('mathematical logic' in Italian), introduces sequent calculus by explaining how the tableau rules generating children in the tree can be classed in $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$ rules:
$$\alpha=(T:\varphi\land\psi)\Rightarrow\alpha_1=(T:\varphi),\alpha_2=(T:\psi);\quad\alpha=(F:\varphi\lor\psi)\Rightarrow\alpha_1=(F:\varphi),\alpha_2=(F:\psi)$$

$$\beta=(T:\varphi\lor\psi)\Rightarrow\beta_1=(T:\varphi),\beta_2=(T:\psi);\quad\beta=(F:\varphi\land\psi)\Rightarrow\beta_1=(F:\varphi),\beta_2=(F:\psi)$$$$\gamma=(T:\forall x\varphi(x))\Rightarrow\gamma(t)=(T:\varphi(t));\quad\gamma=(F:\exists x\varphi(x))\Rightarrow\gamma(t)=(F:\varphi(t))$$$$\delta=(T:\exists x\varphi(x))\Rightarrow\delta(a)=(T:\varphi(a));\quad\delta=(F:\forall x\varphi(x))\Rightarrow\delta(a)=(F:\varphi(a))$$where $T$ means *true* and $F$ *false*. If I correctly understand, $(T:\chi)$ is equivalent to $\chi$, $(F:\chi)$ is equivalent to $\lnot\chi$, and, very roughly speaking, the $\alpha$ rules are those generating childen belonging to the same branch of the parent formula, the $\beta$ rules are "disjunctive", generating childen belonging to two different branches of the parent formula, the $\gamma$ rules substitute a variable $t$ that can represent any element and the $\delta$ rules substitute a constant $a$ that represent the existing element satisfying respectively the truth (first case) or the falsity (second case) of $\varphi(a)$.

*In such a way* -the book says- *the tableau rules can be expressed in the following way, where $S$ indicates a set of marked formulae* and where the label letters are upside down with respect with the usual tree form:$$\frac{S,\alpha_1,\alpha_2}{S,\alpha}\quad\frac{S,\beta_1|S,\beta_2}{S,\beta}\quad\frac{S,\gamma,\gamma(t)}{S,\gamma}\quad\frac{S,\delta(a)}{S,\delta} $$(where I would say that $|$ corresponds to the bifurcation of the tree, to a disjunction, and the commas represent conjunctions, the presence of the formulae, between which they are placed, on the same branch of the tableau tree) and, the text says, *if we use the notation $[]$ for sequents, we get the following compact notation*$$\frac{[S,\alpha_1,\alpha_2]}{[S,\alpha]}\quad\frac{[S,\beta_1]\quad[S,\beta_2]}{[S,\beta]}\quad\frac{[S,\gamma(t)]}{[S,\gamma]}\quad\frac{[S,\delta(a)]}{[S,\delta]} .$$ Here my problems of understanding begin, indeed I know that a sequent is a formula $\Phi\vdash\Psi$ meaning that from all the formulae in $\Phi$ at least one of the formulae in $\Psi$ follows, but I am not sure how that appears in those formulae. Then the text says that, *if we rewrite these rules in the original sequent notation* we get $$\frac{\Gamma,\varphi,\psi\vdash\Delta}{\Gamma,\varphi\land\psi\vdash\Delta}\quad\frac{\Gamma\vdash\Delta,\varphi;\quad\Gamma\vdash\Delta,\psi}{\Gamma\vdash\Delta,\varphi\land\psi}\quad\frac{\Gamma\vdash\Delta,\varphi,\psi}{\Gamma\vdash\Delta,\varphi\lor\psi}\quad\frac{\Gamma,\varphi\vdash\Delta;\quad\Gamma,\psi\vdash\Delta}{\Gamma,\varphi\lor\psi\vdash\Delta}$$ $$\frac{\Gamma,\varphi\vdash\Delta,\psi}{\Gamma\vdash\Delta,\varphi\rightarrow\psi}\quad\frac{\Gamma\vdash\Delta,\varphi;\quad\Gamma,\psi\vdash\Delta}{\Gamma,\varphi\rightarrow\psi\vdash\Delta}\quad\frac{\Gamma,\varphi\vdash\Delta}{\Gamma\vdash\Delta,\lnot\varphi}\quad\frac{\Gamma\vdash\Delta,\varphi}{\Gamma,\lnot\varphi\vdash\Delta}$$$$\frac{\Gamma,\varphi(t)\vdash\Delta}{\Gamma,\forall x\varphi(x)\vdash\Delta}\quad\frac{\Gamma\vdash\Delta,\varphi(a)}{\Gamma\vdash\Delta,\forall x\varphi(x)}\quad\frac{\Gamma\vdash\Delta,\varphi(t)}{\Gamma\vdash\Delta,\exists x\varphi(x)}\quad\frac{\Gamma,\varphi(a)\vdash\Delta}{\Gamma,\exists x\varphi(x)\vdash\Delta}$$
I see that the formulae above and under the line are equivalent in predicate logic (with some doubt about the meaning of $a$ and $t$) if we read "$;$" as *and* and if we read the comma as $\land$ when it precedes $\vdash$ and as $\lor$ when it follows it. But I do not see at all how they are a rewriting of the preceding formulae containing $S,\alpha,\alpha_1,\alpha_2, \beta,$... How are they related to them? I have searched very much in the Internet and on books, but I find no information...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relation between [sequent calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus) and [tableaux method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux) is very well presented in the "little classics" :

- Raymond Smullyan, [First-Order Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=kgvhQ-oSZiUC&pg=PR4) (1968).

For the "truth trees" proof procedure, see also :

- Peter Smith, [An Introduction to Formal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=bX91C6GOBkcC&printsec=frontcover) (2003).

You can see also :

- Stephen Simpson, [Mathematical Logic](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/logic.pdf) (2013).

---

The *semantics* for *sequents*, in brief, is the following [see Gaisi Takeuti, [Proof Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=Idl6K-W69NYC&pg=PA9) (2nd ed - 1987), page 9] :

> intuitively a *sequent* $\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_m \vdash \delta_1, \ldots, \delta_n$ means :
>
> > "if $\gamma_1 \land \ldots \land \gamma_m$, then $\delta_1 \lor \ldots \lor \delta_n$.

Then we have [page 41] :

> A sequent $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$ is *satisfied* [in an interpretation $\mathfrak I$] if either some formula in $\Gamma$ is not satisfied by $\mathfrak I$, or some formula in $\Delta$ is satisfied by $\mathfrak I$. A sequent is *valid* it it satisfied in every interpretation.

Thus, the sequent $\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_m \vdash \delta_1, \ldots, \delta_n$ is "semantically equivalent" to :

> > $(\gamma_1 \land \ldots \land \gamma_m) \rightarrow (\delta_1 \lor \ldots \lor \delta_n)$.

---

Regarding specifically the relationship between tableaux and sequent calculus, you can see Smullyan's book; **Ch.XI : Gentzen Systems** is devoted to explain the "transition" from the first to the second.

Historically Gentzen developer sequent calculus in the '30s and Beth, Hintikka and Smullyan derived from it, in the '50s-'60s, the tableaux method.

The easiest way  is to start from tha last one.

It is a "refutation" procedure: it proves $\varphi$ building a refutation tree for $\lnot \varphi$. The tree is built decomposing the root formula according to the rules.

The rules have the nice property [Smullyan, page 25] :

> that any immediate extension of a tableau which is true (under a given interpretation) is again true (under the given interpretation). [...] Now a closed tableau $\mathfrak T$ obviously cannot be true under any interpretation, hence [...] the origin of any closed tableau must be unsatisfiable.

Conclusion : if the tableau for $\lnot \varphi$ closes, then $\lnot \varphi$ is *unsatisfiable*, and thus $\varphi$ is *valid* (a *tautology*, if it is a propositional formula).

---

The tableau rules correspond to the sequent calculus rules "read" bottom-up, like in the *root-first proof search* procedure [see e.g.: Jan von Plato, [Elements of Logical Reasoning](https://books.google.it/books?id=QrdEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA64) (2013), page 64-on].

Consider e.g. the connective $\land$; its "signed" rules are :

> $$\frac{\displaystyle   \frac{\displaystyle   T(X \land Y)}{TX}}{TY}\quad\frac{F(X \land Y)}{FX | FY}$$

and compare with the left- and right-rules of sequent calculus :

> $$\frac{\Gamma,\varphi,\psi\vdash\Delta}{\Gamma,\varphi\land\psi\vdash\Delta}\quad\frac{\Gamma\vdash\Delta,\varphi\quad\Gamma\vdash\Delta,\psi}{\Gamma\vdash\Delta,\varphi\land\psi}$$

Read the left one ($\land$-left) "bottom-up".

The intended meaning of the rule, according to the above semantics, is that the lower sequent is *falsified* when "all elements of $\Gamma, \varphi\land\psi$ are *true* and all element of $\Delta$ are *false*".

Thus, forgetting about the *contexts*: $\Gamma, \Delta$, this implies that both $\varphi$ and $\psi$ must be *true*.

And this, in turn, means that the upper sequent is *falsified*.

Regarding the right sequent-rule ($\land$-right), the lower sequent is *falsified* when: "all elements of $\Gamma$ are *true* and all elements of $\Delta, \varphi\land\psi$ are *false*".

Forgetting about the "contexts" again, we have that this implies that at least one between $\varphi, \psi$ must be *false*, and this is the gist of the tableau rule for $F\land$.

This "reading" explains also the peculiar form of *axioms* in sequent calculus: $A \vdash A$.

With the *root-first proof search* procedure, the proof ends (positively) when all branches of the "growing tree" reach an axiom.

But, according again to the above semantics, the sequent $A \vdash A$ cannot be *falsified*, because the condition: "all elements of $\{ A \}$ are *true* and all elements of $\{ A \}$ are *false*" will never hold.

This condition is corresponding to the contradiction that allows us to "cross" a branch in a tableau.

*Note* The peculiarity of sequent rules (in a suitable designed calculus) is that they are, so to say, "hyper sound", i.e. the conclusion is *true* **iff** the premises are (this is not so for "traditional" inference rules, like e.g. *modus ponens*).

---

Regarding the *sequent* rules for quantifiers, $a$ in $\forall$-right and $\exists$-left is a *free* variable, with the proviso : $a$ not occurring in $\Gamma, \Delta$.

The $t$ in $\forall$-left and $\exists$-right is a *term*, with no restrictions.

Intuitively, $\forall$-right is $\forall$-introduction of *Natural Deduction* : if $\Gamma \vdash \varphi(y)$, then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \varphi^y_x$, provided that $y$ is not free in $\Gamma$.

$\forall$-left instead, corresponds to $\forall$-elimination of *Natural Deduction* : if $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \varphi$, then $\Gamma \vdash \varphi^x_t$, where $t$ is a term whatever, substitutable for $x$ in $\varphi$.

---

---

You can see also :

- Mordechai Ben-Ari, [Mathematical Logic for Computer Science](https://books.google.it/books?id=RyDrAgAAQBAJ) (3rd ed - 2012), **Ch.3.2.1 The Relationship Between [Gentzen System] $\mathcal G$ and Semantic Tableaux**, page 53-on.

Comment: @Self-teachingDavide - see Smullyan, page 106 ... but the little book is "quite compressed", with a lot of results not so easy to be grasped at a first reading. Thus, you have to read it until page 106 ...

Comment: @Self-teachingDavide - a good "companion" to Smullyan's book is : Melvin Fitting, [First-Order Logic and Automated Theorem Proving](https://books.google.it/books?id=nYN0dBrCpmMC&pg=PR1) (1990).

Comment: You tell me that the "denominator" of $\frac{\Gamma\vdash\Delta ,\varphi\quad\Gamma\vdash\Delta ,\psi}{\Gamma\vdash\Delta ,\varphi\land\psi}$ means that "if some element of $\Gamma$ is false, then all elements of $\Delta,\varphi\land\psi$ must be false" while the "numerator" means "if some element of $\Gamma$ is false, then all elements of $\Delta,\varphi$ ($\Delta,\psi$ respectively) must be false"...

Comment: ...while in $\frac{\Gamma,\varphi,\psi\vdash \Delta}{\Gamma,\varphi\land\psi\vdash \Delta}$ the meaning of both is, if I understand, "if all elements of $\Gamma\cup\{\varphi,\psi\}$ are true, then at least one element of $\Delta$ is true"...

Comment: ...If I correctly understand symbol $\vdash$ means implication ($\rightarrow$) in $\frac{\Gamma,\varphi,\psi\vdash \Delta}{\Gamma,\varphi\land\psi\vdash \Delta}$ and reverse implication ($\leftarrow$), in $\frac{\Gamma\vdash\Delta ,\varphi\quad\Gamma\vdash\Delta ,\psi}{\Gamma\vdash\Delta ,\varphi\land\psi}$ (while the commas always are "and" before $\vdash$ and "or" after it): how do we know that? Thank you so much for the explanations and the many references!

Comment: @Self-teachingDavide . the sequent $γ_1,…,γ_m⊢δ_1,…,δ_n$ is "semantically equivalent" to : $\vdash (γ_1∧…∧γ_m)→(δ_1∨…∨δ_n)$. Thus, truth conditions for $\rightarrow$ apply: it is true when the antecedent is *false* (and being a *conjunction*, it is enough that one of $\γ_i$ is *false*) or when the consequent is *true* (and being a *disjunction*, it is enough that one of $\δ_j$ is *true*).

Comment: OK, so no difference in the meaning of the symbols above and under the line. Thank you so much again!

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Maybe I'm missing something here: "if some element of $\Gamma$ is false, then all elements of $\Delta,  \varphi\land\psi$ must be false" [again, read it as a conditional; thus, if at least one element in $\Gamma$ is false, "reading" it as a *conjunction*, the antecedent is false; thus in order to satisfy the complete sequent, also the consequent must be false" The fact that the antecedent is false doesn't say anything about the consequent... $\varphi\land\psi\vdash\psi$ doesn't tell us   $\neg\left(\varphi\land\psi\right)\vdash\neg\psi$!

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I understand that, I was just pointing out the mistake. :) The edit fixes that issue, but your explanation now suggests proofs switch between assuming a *sequent* is true and that it is false—if we (root first) apply $\land$-left and then $\land$-right, by your explanation we've applied one tableau rule assuming the *sequent* is true, and the next assuming it is false. But we of course can't normally switch assumptions in the middle of a proof, and so the proof as a whole isn't explained.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA We should instead understand ourselves to be supposing the sequent is false the whole time, reading the sequent $\Gamma : \Delta$ as the supposition "every wff in $\Gamma$ is true and every wff in $\Delta$ is false." Tableau rules for T apply to the wffs in $\Gamma$ because they are supposed true *the whole time*, and the tableau rules for F apply to the wffs in $\Delta$ because they are supposed false *the whole time*. Reading it this way, we stop at $\varphi : \varphi$ because we've derived a contradiction, just like in a tableau proof.

Comment: @Hungry - thanks to your comment, I've corrected the errors. :-)